# Azure B2C handle cancel button in custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Is there anyway to handle where the cancel button redirects from within a custom policy. I am actually not going to have a custom webapp behind this policy and the app that is there is not customizable by myself.

I am working with the kind of setup in this document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/partner-f5

I am hoping for something similar to how we can now handle the forgot password within the custom policy.

Comment: redirect_url query parameter

Comment: What can I do with the redirect_url parameter?

Comment: is there any error pop up when u cancelling the button ?

Answer (score 0):

If a user clicks the ***"Cancel button"*** and then wants to go back to the home page, you'll need to either catch the error.

```json
https://<b2ctenant>.b2clogin.com/<b2ctenant>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_signupsignin
&client_id=your_client_id  
&nonce=defaultNonce  
&redirect_uri=your_redirect_uri  
&scope=your_scope  
&response_type=id_token  
&prompt=login
```

The redirect URI will be present in the URL. Once you click cancel button it will automatically redirect to the URL you specified.

***Reference:***

[Cancel button Azure B2C - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/721436/cancel-button-azure-btc.html) credits by  ***JamesTran-MSFT***